# Variance of $(X-\mu)^2+\mu^2 $ smaller than the variance of $X^2$, but how much

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, variance

I have managed to prove that $Var(X^2) \ge Var((X-\mu)^2+\mu^2) $.

This is what I got with help from @Calvin Khor.
$Var(X^2) - Var((X-\mu)^2+\mu^2) = 4E(X)E[X(X-E(X))^2]$

Now I wonder, with what factor is the variance of $(X-\mu)^2+\mu^2$ smaller than the variance of $X^2$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $\mu = E(X)$ here?

Comment: Yes! Worth noting is that X has zero skewness as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Variance or $\sigma^2$ is $E\left[(X-\mu)^2\right]$ and do a little algebra we get $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$, considering $\mu=E(X)$

Comment: Note it's the variance of $X^2$, not $X$ itself.

Comment: Then the $\sigma^2(X^2)= E\left[(X^2-E(X^2))^2\right]$

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Hmm can you give me one more hint, I don't really know where to go from there. I've already done that.

Comment: I think the first one is from definiton (i'm not sure). So if you wanna find $X^2$ just subtitute $X=X^2$

Comment: I have already done that, now I need to find with what factor the variance is smaller then.